# Importing a large repository to GitHub using the native import feature

Tags: github, import, repository, large-files

I'm importing a set of repositories from BitBucket (using the native GitHub import), and I'm running into an error for a particular one:

"This repository is too large."

I know that this is not the same as the "large file" issue, as I ran into that with another repository, and it told me specifically which files were a problem.

With this error, I can't find any information about it, and GH doesn't seem to have documented this particular message. The repo is way under the 100GB size limit, but maybe there's a hidden import limit (it is over 1GB)?

Any known way to get around this, or more about the error that anyone knows?